# How to install ssl certificate without IIS in windows server 2016?

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2016

I have a project based on asp.net core MVC; I want to use an SSL certificate for using https, but when running my project, it didn't show https address. I can't use IIS in my windows server.but in windows 10 everything is ok.

I'm trying install SSL certificate in windows server for using https in my project.

```
      public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            var host = "0.0.0.0";
            var http_port = 40000;
            var https_port = 40001;

            if (args.Length > 0) host = args[0].Trim();
            if (args.Length > 1) http_port = Convert.ToInt32(args[1].Trim());
            if (args.Length > 2) https_port = Convert.ToInt32(args[2].Trim());


            return
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    //
                    .UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
                        options.Limits.MaxRequestBufferSize = null;
                        options.Limits.MaxRequestHeaderCount = 1000;
                        options.Limits.MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize = 256 * 1024;

                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse(host), http_port);

                        using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My))
                        {
                            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                            var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost", false);
                            if (certs.Count > 0)
                            {
                                var certificate = certs[0];

                                options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse(host), https_port, listenOptions =>
                                {
                                    listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }).Build();

        }
```

I expect the output see https://0.0.0.0:40001, but in windows server I only have http://0.0.0.0:40000.

image of Windows server
[Windows server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgkoX.png)

image of Windows 10:
[Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpWtH.png)

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice, after I used `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` I got this error crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.

Comment: Sorry, I tried running your code and it worked for me. Maybe try changing `new X509Store(StoreName.My)` to `new X509Store()` to use the default store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand things correctly, you are having a hard time using SSL in you development environment. I suggest you look here [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET CORE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). At this point on the page, [Trust the ASP.NET Core Development Certificates..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio),you'll probably find the solution to your problem.

Answer (score -3):

Step 1:  enable IIS feature in your  machine to host. Then go to administrative tool>IIS manager.

Step 2 : Select site for which you want to enable ssl.

Step 3: In the action panel on right side you will have  Edit site and select binding

Step 4 : in site binding if it already defined, click close or

1.click add

2.select https

3. In ssl certificate, select certificate
4. Click ok then close

Step 5: In connection panel, under site> click site again to display selected website homepage.

Step 6: In selected website, click on SSL setting

Step 7: In ssl setting, select require ssl and under client certificate select accept.

Step 8: apply

Comment: Downvoted as the OP clearly says he can't use IIS.